# How can I write code that uses a different method for different parameters without using "if-else if"?

Tags: java, design-patterns

To me, `if`-`else if` is too long and hard to read.

Is there some table-driven approach I can use to map an input value to call a specific method for that value?

For example:

```
for(String id:ids){

    Test test = new Test();

    if(id == "101") {    
        test.method1();
    }else if(id=="102") {
        test.method2();
    }else if(id=="103"){
        test.method3();
     ...
```

Comment: a HashMap of IDs and methods (i.e, K,V) can work. So, yes, a table driven approach will work.

Comment: write switch statement... I know that these days people dont use it much but there is no harm in it..

Comment: @praveen_mohan - 1. Switch case for Strings(IDs) needs a higher Java version. 2. He will still have to write several switch cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
...
static Map<String,Method> methods = new HashMap<String,Method>();
...
static {
    methods.put("101",Test.class.getMethod("method1",null));
    methods.put("102",Test.class.getMethod("method2",null));
    ...
}
...
for( String id : ids ) {
    Test test = new Test();
    Method m = methods.get(id);
    if (m != null) {
        m.invoke(test,null);
    }
}
```

Of course, all this really does is trade the pain of the if/else chain for the pain of initializing the hash with all the methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to call method. Construct the method name from the string and Use Method Class from `java.lang.reflect` namespace to invoke the method and pass parameters.
Something like this

```
Method theMethod = yourClass.getClass().getMethod("methodName", null);
method.invoke(yourClass, );
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is, your code is not quite correct, as it's using `==` to check equality of strings.

You should use the `equals` method:

```
for(String id: ids){

    Test test = new Test();

    if(id.equals("101")) {
        test.method1();
    }else if(id.equals("102")) {
        test.method2();
    }else if(id.equals("102")){
        test.method3();
    // etc.
    }
}
```

Other answers have suggested a creating a method map `Map<String,Method>` and using reflection.  This will work and may be perfectly reasonable for your use, but loses some compile-time type safety checks.

You can get those checks back by defining an interface and populating a map with instances of that interface:

```
interface TestMethod {
   void  execute(Test test);
}

private static HashMap<String, TestMethod> methodMap = new HashMap<String, TestMethod>();

static {
    methodMap.put("101", new TestMethod(){
        @Override
        public void execute(Test test) {
            test.method1();
        }
    });
    methodMap.put("102", new TestMethod(){
        @Override
        public void execute(Test test) {
            test.method2();
        }
    });
    methodMap.put("103", new TestMethod() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Test test) {
            test.method3();
        }
    });
    // etc.
}
```

and then your loop can be coded as

```
for (String id: ids) {
    Test test = new Test();
    methodMap.get(id).execute(test);
}
```

As it is here, this unfortunately makes the code longer and leaves it *at least* as difficult to read.  But if you're using Java 8, you can use [lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to populate the map, which would make the static initializer block look more like:

```
static {
    methodMap.put("101", t -> t.method1();
    methodMap.put("102", t -> t.method2();
    methodMap.put("103", t -> t.method3();
    // etc.
}
```

and then it might actually be worth doing.

However, if this sort of conditional based on some kind of string "code" is common in your application, and *especially if you have multiple conditionals depending on the same codes*, you might want a much broader redesign to encapsulate the different actions done for the different codes in a class hierarchy and use polymorphism instead of either if-else (or switch) or a method map lookup.  You're still likely to need some conditionals to build the instances of your classes, but the code might be greatly improved.